# Using a custom parser with flask_smorest and/or marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, webargs, flask-smorest

I'm using [flask-smorest](https://flask-smorest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#), the Flask/Marshmallow-based REST API framework and would like to be able to parse requests made with the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) JavaScript library, specifically for arrays passed via the querystring.

Axios sends arrays like this:

```
/api/v1/items/?types[]=cd&types[]=dvd
```

I need to create a [custom parser](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-parsers) for this (see also the helpful responses on the [ticket I created](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/webargs/issues/517)) so I was able to cobble together a rudimentary parser that serves my purpose.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to tell flask_smorest or marshmallow to use this custom parser for my API's `MethodView`-based endpoints.

I was also thinking of creating a custom field in my `Schema`, but there too I don't know how I can access the querystring so that it can be parsed correctly.

So what is the best way to integrate the parser for a specific type of querystring array encoding in flask_smorest/marshmallow?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your parser and perhaps a simplified case to reproduce and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created a parser as demonstrated in [webargs docs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-parsers), all you need to do is to tell your flask-smorest app to use this custom parser in place of default `FlaskParser`.

This is done by overriding `Blueprint` and overriding `ARGUMENTS_PARSER` from `ArgumentsMixin`:

```
import flask_smorest

class Blueprint(flask_smorest.Blueprint):

    ARGUMENTS_PARSER = CustomParser()
```